# Kryo - How to keep the server running and waiting for requests

Tags: java, kryo

I use [Kryo-net](https://code.google.com/p/kryonet/) for send and receive messages. On the server side I open new thread and sets the server, the problem is that the thread is ended at the end of the code so there isnt really listener for requests.

```
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Connection;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Listener;
import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Server;

public class MessagingServer implements Runnable{
  private Server server;

  public void stop(){
    this.server.stop();
  }  

  public MessagingServer(){ 
    this.server = new Server();
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    try{
      if(server!=null){ stop(); }      

      this.server.start();
      this.server.bind(54555, 54777);

      Kryo kryo = this.server.getKryo();
      kryo.register(NewRequiredJobRequest.class);
      kryo.register(NewRequiredJobResponse.class);

      server.addListener(new Listener() {
         @Override
         public void received (Connection connection, Object object) {
            if (object instanceof HelloRequest) {
               HelloRequest request = (HelloRequest)object;
               System.out.println(request.text);

               HelloResponse response = new HelloResponse();
               response.text = "Thanks!";
               connection.sendTCP(response);
            }
         }
      });
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("kryo server exception"));
    } 

    // once the code reach here the thread is ended..
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Server object probably has some sort of `listen` or `accept` method that must run in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

KryoNet Client#start and Server#start starts a daemon thread. If you have no other non-daemon threads in your app:

```
new Thread(client).start();
new Thread(server).start();
```

Answer (score -1):

I've never use kryo, but I think this will help.

```
    import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo;
    import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Connection;
    import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Listener;
    import com.esotericsoftware.kryonet.Server;

    public class MessagingServer implements Runnable{
      private Server server;

      public void stop(){
        this.server.stop();
      }  

      public MessagingServer(){ 
        this.server = new Server();
      }

      @Override
      public void run() {
        try{
          if(server!=null){ stop(); }      

          this.server.start();
          this.server.bind(54555, 54777);

          while(true) {

           Kryo kryo = this.server.getKryo();
           kryo.register(NewRequiredJobRequest.class);
           kryo.register(NewRequiredJobResponse.class);

           server.addListener(new Listener() {
             @Override
             public void received (Connection connection, Object object) {
                if (object instanceof HelloRequest) {
                   HelloRequest request = (HelloRequest)object;
                   System.out.println(request.text);

                   HelloResponse response = new HelloResponse();
                   response.text = "Thanks!";
                   connection.sendTCP(response);
                }
             }
           });
         }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("kryo server exception"));
        } 

      }
    }
```

Comment: This just add listeners.